# Can I make MonoDevelop look good on a Retina display?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, retina-display, gtk#, xamarin

I bought a new Retina MacBook Pro to develop for iOS with MonoTouch.
It is extremely frustrating that, probably because it is built on Gtk#, MonoDevelop is very blurry.

[image: MonoDevelop blurry on Retina display]

I can cope with blurry UI but I can't read or write code because it hurts my eyes.

What is the current status of Retina support in Gtk# and MonoDevelop?
Is there any (experimental) compile flag at least to enable proper code rendering?

If I want to contribute, which component is in charge of this? Is it Gtk# or Gtk itself?

Comment: There is an [open bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6293) with Xamarin. It doesn't seem like any work has been done on it, though I'm sure the guys there would love a patch.

Comment: Thanks for finding the bug. I'm curious about the reason for downvote.

Comment: Wasn't me that downvoted. Anyway, if you open up property sheet of MonoDevelop.app (right click, "Get Info"), is there a checkbox for "Open in low resolution"? This might be a usable, temporary work around.

Comment: @vcsjones: Yes, it is checked and grayed out.

Comment: There is a temporary work around I used for WebStorm that worked well. It may work for MonoDevelop too. Look here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87500#comment=27-346931

Comment: @vcsjones: You saved my eyes. Please post your comment as answer so I could mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have enabled this in MonoDevelop master so it'll be included in future releases: https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/commit/8d2c22ca696f64eb258e57a2aa3c0468ff330148

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Update

This has been fixed as of [MonoDevelop 3.0.4](http://monodevelop.com/Download/What%27s_new_in_MonoDevelop_3.0.4):

> Other improvements and bug fixes
>
> - Fixed rendering on MacBook with retina display

So just go and [download it](http://monodevelop.com/Download/What%27s_new_in_MonoDevelop_3.0.4).

#### Workaround for Older Versions (and other apps, too)

There is a [temporary work around](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87500#comment=27-346931) I used for WebStorm that worked well. It should work for MonoDevelop too.

You can use that in the mean time until the Xamarin folks get an update to MonoDevelop out.
Here it goes:

1. Locate MonoDevelop in Applications and click **Show Package Contents**

[image]

2. Open `Contents/Info.plist` in any editor and add this after opening `<dict>`:

   ```
   <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
   <true/>
   ```
3. Copy and paste MonoDevelop app bundle, delete the old one and rename the new one back to MonoDevelop. This will flush system caches.

You will notice that MonoDevelop.app info now has Low Resolution option unchecked and the code renders smoothly.

[image]

Comment: Is there a solution for monodevelop (4.0.1, bundled with Unity 4.6) under windows (bootcamp)?